# When use pooled data source X simple data source

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

What is main difference  in current JBoss (6.0 or 7.x) version for using standard data source and pooled data source. 
Which one to use in which environment.

I have experience with jboss 4.2. I started using simple data source and very soon I hit problem with loosing connection during time.

I solved issue with using c3p0 pooled data source. c3p0  double checked  connections for me and renewed them after defined time. So every time I need to use data source I got valid jdbc connection.

However when I went trough Jboss 6 documentation I did not find any mention about pooled data source any more. 
So, should I still used pooled data source. If so when, and what is their limits.